# Drawing lines at specific vertices of other lines in Three.js

Tags: three.js, drawing, lines

I am making a drawing program in Three.js.  I can draw lines on various axes and can rotate them around.  good so far

what I need is a pattern to follow in order to add to a line (source_line) along a one of its axes as the mouse draws the new line. I am just learning graphics programming and am unsure of the correct way to go about this.  I've looked at some of the examples but don't see much about dynamically drawn vertices from mouse events w/r/to other objects.

What is the best way to make my mouse draw in proximity to the source_line vertex(versus whatever the mouse.unproject(camera) determines)? Do I edit the camera near/far params or translate the mouse vector during the onmousemove (via distance vector)?  In this fiddle, you can see how I told the new_line vertex to begin with the source_line z setting- it 'works', but I know it isn't the right approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/cindy/zc34qn59/2/

```
//in mousedown

if (DRAWMODE){
            bIsDrawing=true;
            if ( currentIntersectedPoint !== undefined ) {
            //yes, we have an object of interest/ source_line to add to
                initNewLine(currentIntersectedPoint, false);

            }else{
                initNewLine(mouse, true);
            }
```

or, would I calculate the overall bounding box of the source_line, get the normals and perhaps do something like turning the cursor into a plane that tilts perpendicularly along the source_line axes  (like Tilt brush seems to do)?

any pointers (haha pun intended) are appreciated